# Why i cant get a Position and Distance in Console . I want to get a Position and a Distance when i click my control in a plane

Tags: unity-game-engine

This is my Distance Code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Distance : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler
{
    public GameObject Camera; 
    public GameObject Object; 
    public float Distance_;

    void Start()
    {

    }


    
    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Distance_ = Vector3.Distance(Camera.transform.position, Object.transform.position);  

        Debug.Log("Distance: " + Distance_); 
    
        }
}
```

This is my Position code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Position : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler
{
    public Vector3 worldPosition;
    Plane plane = new Plane(Vector3.up, 0);
    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        float distance;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(eventData.position);
        if (plane.Raycast(ray, out distance))
        {
            worldPosition = ray.GetPoint(distance);

            Debug.Log("Position: " + worldPosition);

            //print("Position: " + worldPosition);
        }
    }
}
```

I was copy this 2 script in my Plane but it is not working
I was copy this 2 script in my Plane but it is not workingI was copy this 2 script in my Plane but it is not workingI was copy this 2 script in my Plane but it is not workingI was copy this 2 script in my Plane but it is not workingI was copy this 2 script in my Plane but it is not workingI was copy this 2 script in my Plane but it is not working
I was copy this 2 script in my Plane but it is not working
v
I was copy this 2 script in my Plane but it is not working

I was copy this 2 script in my Plane but it is not workingI was copy this 2 script in my Plane but it is not workingI was copy this 2 script in my Plane but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Your problem probably is of click detection. Try Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0);